# Retrieved Pinterest Access Token v Token generator Tool

Tags: pinterest

what is the difference between the access token that can be retrieved through the auth process and the one that is generated here:
https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/access_token/

Should the generated one be used for a live app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token generated in the Token Generator on the developer site is a temp/demo token that is correlated with the "Pinterest" app. When you build your own app and put users through the auth process it will generate a token corresponding to YOUR app. Definitely don't use the generated one for a live app, always generate a new toke for each individual user. Each token corresponds to a user + app, and each user + app combination is rate limited among other things, so you won't want all your users tied to the same token.

Hope that helps!